# How do you change the user id from a list of names to the discord username and discrimination?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a command that looks like this: !command @user @user where the bot responds with @user,@user. I currently have this code to get the list of arguments and the embed:

```
let people = message.content.slice(6).trim().split(/ +/g);
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .addField(`**${people}**`)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
        message.channel.send(embed);
```

and the embed I made shows this: <@!number>,<@number>.
How do I make it so it shows the actual username and discrimination without pinging the users again in the message?

Comment: Not too clear but you could use ${people}.username or .id

Answer (score 0):

You could use Discord's [`MessageMentions.USERS_PATTERN`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=s-USERS_PATTERN) (which is `/<@!?(\d{17,19})>/g`) and use the matched ID (the first capture group) to get the user's [`tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag):

```js
`**${people.replace(MessageMentions.USERS_PATTERN, (_, $1) => message.client.users.cache.get($1).tag)}**`
```

```js
const MessageMentions = {USERS_PATTERN: /<@!?(\d{17,19})>/g}
const message = {client: {users: {cache: new Map([
  ['712454579618447360', {tag: 'user1#1234'}],
  ['712454581979840513', {tag: 'user2#5678'}]
])}}}
const people = '<@712454579618447360> <@!712454581979840513>'

console.log(`**${people.replace(MessageMentions.USERS_PATTERN, (_, $1) => message.client.users.cache.get($1).tag)}**`)
```